# ES6 Classes: Unexpected token in script?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, class-fields

I'm copying an example trying to learn ES6 but i'm getting a compile error:

```
Unexpected token (2:5)
```

It appears to be referring to the count = 0;

What am I doing wrong?

```
class Counter {
    count = 0;

    constructor() {
        setInterval(function() {
            this.tick();
        }.bind(this), 1000);
    }

    tick() {
        this.count ++;
        console.log(this.count);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to declare your variable first - so use `var` or `let` (preferably `let`) to let javascript know you are declaring. Otherwise the `=` is actually invalid as it cannot be assigned.

Comment: You might want to mention which compiler you're using.

Comment: im using gulp/elixir

Comment: let or var does not seem to fix

Comment: Where did you get the example from? That's not ES6. I recommend to learn from a source that actually is about ES6.

Answer (score 28):

In ES2015, when using the `class` syntax, you need to define instance variables either in the constructor or one of the methods (there is a proposal for the next iteration, ES2016, to allow for your syntax: [ES Class Fields & Static Properties](https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-static-properties-and-fields))

```
class Counter {

    constructor() {
        this.count = 0;
        setInterval(function() {
            this.tick();
        }.bind(this), 1000);
    }

    tick() {
        this.count++;
        console.log(this.count);
    }
}

var c = new Counter();
```

Check out the fiddle:

http://www.es6fiddle.net/ifjtvu5f/

Comment: Nevermind me, it's working. I didnt' figure out those numbers wheren't the console's line number

Answer (score 2):

3 years late so you probably figured it out, but I placed the count variable in the constructor

```
class Counter {
    constructor(count = 0) {
      this.count = count
        setInterval(function() {
            this.tick();
        }.bind(this), 1000);
    }

    tick() {
        this.count ++;
        console.log(this.count);
    }
}

let counter = new Counter;
counter.tick()
```

gave it more control by calling the tick function

```
class Counter {
    constructor(count = 0) {
      this.count = count;
    }

    tick() {
        let count = this.count;
        setInterval(function() {
         console.log(count++);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
let counter = new Counter;

// counter.tick()
```

Comment: Seems identical to the [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33042437/6243352) so I'm not sure what value this adds. `let counter = new Counter;` seems incorrect. You probably want to call the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's the compiler issue. Check what version of Babel you're using.

In my case I missed the `babel-preset-stage-0` dependency.