# Javascript syntax error on rails/browserify application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, nginx, heroku, browserify

I have been trying to deploy my rails/browserify application via Heroku, Nginx and Apache and I keep running into the same error. When the assets get precompiled via `bundle exec rake assets:precompile db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production` one of my JS classes produces a syntax error. I found a similar issue here: [ES6 Classes: Unexpected token in script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33042084/es6-classes-unexpected-token-in-script)
 but I do not have any variable declarations outside of my constructor or methods.

The error:

```js
rake aborted!
ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (Game)
JS_Parse_Error.get ((execjs):3538:621)
(execjs):4060:47
(execjs):1:102
Object.<anonymous> ((execjs):1:120)
Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
Module.load (module.js:488:32)
tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
```

The Javascript class that is producing the syntax error:

```js
class Game {

  constructor(attributes) {
      this.id = attributes.id;
      this.characters = attributes.characters;
      this.quotes = attributes.game_quotes;
      this.state = attributes.state;
      this.completed = attributes.completed;
  }

  score() {
      if (this.completed == true) {
          var score = 0;
          for (var i = 0; i < this.state.length; i++) {
              if (this.state[i] == true) {
                  score++;
              }
          }
          return score;
      } else {
          return "Game Incomplete";
      }
  }

  percentageScore() {
      if (this.score() >= 0) {
          return (this.score() * 10 + "%");
      } else {
          return "Game Incomplete";
      }
  }

  }
```

Where is the syntax error?

Here is a link to the repository of my application if you need some context: [Repository](https://github.com/joelbitar1986/who_said_it)

Any help from the community would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance if you can offer any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error goes away by commenting out the following line in `config/environments/production.rb`

`config.assets.js_compressor = ...`