# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'class'

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a class GameState with a constructor function to assign my variables. I keep getting the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'class' - but all of the documentation I can find says to do it this way. I'm not sure what's wrong.
MDN Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor

I also found this solution on stack overflow which also looks like what I have, but I'm still getting an error. [ES6 Classes: Unexpected token in script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33042084/es6-classes-unexpected-token-in-script)

I tried commenting out all of my code and pasting an example from MDN and it is throwing the same error https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class

Could someone please help me out? I'm pretty new to programming but all of the documentation looks right, I'm still lost. Code below for reference.

```
class GameState {
    constructor() {
        this.board = [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null];
        this.whoseTurn = 1;
        this.winner = null;
    }
}

let gs = new GameState();
```

Comment: What is the code before `class GameState {`?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: See the [Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#browser_compatibility) table

Comment: If you are using Internet Explorer, it's no wonder you get the error …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly check the syntax before the `class` statement as [@VLAZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz) said and put a semicolon if there is not one. Missing semicolons can cause strange errors.

The `class` statement is a feature new in ES2015. If you are using an older browser (eg. Internet Explorer) this will not work. Instead try a constructor *function*:

```js
function GameState() {
  if (!(this instanceof GameState)) { //Function was called without the "new" keyword, so we return an instance instead of creating one.
    return new GameState();
  }
  this.board = [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null];
  this.whoseTurn = 1;
  this.winner = null;
}
  
  

let gs = new GameState();

console.log(gs);
```

You can add `prototype` functions with `GameState.prototype`

```js
function GameState() {
  if (!(this instanceof GameState)) { //Function was called without the "new" keyword, so we return an instance instead of creating one.
    return new GameState();
  }
  this.board = [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null];
  this.whoseTurn = 1;
  this.winner = null;
}
  
GameState.prototype.getBoard = function () {
  return this.board;
};

let gs = new GameState();

console.log(gs.getBoard());
```

Comment: Hey guys, I have the same error right now, but in my case class is literally at the very first start of the script..